# Using the largeIcon field of Notification class, like the Gmail notification

Tags: android, reflection, notifications, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm developing an app that shows a notification for an incoming message.  I would like the notification to display a bitmap rather than the app icon.
I believe I can do this in Honeycomb only, using the largeIcon field in the Notification class.
I'm using reflection to determine if the device is running Honeycomb, and if so I am populating the largeIcon field with a bitmap, like so:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, ticketText, when);

String sClassName = "android.app.Notification";
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            Class classToInvestigate = Class.forName(sClassName);
            String strNewFieldName = "largeIcon";
            Field largeIconField = classToInvestigate.getField(strNewFieldName);

            largeIconField.set(notification, photoBitmap);

            Log.e(TAG, "Notification bitmap worked properly");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification bitmap error; ClassNotFoundException: " + e);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification bitmap error; NoSuchFieldException: " + e);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification bitmap error; SecurityException: " + e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification bitmap error; UnknownException: " + e);
        }
```

According to my log, no exception is fired when the notification displays.  However, the bitmap doesn't show up on the notification, only the app icon.

Any ideas?

Comment: Should I give more context?  Is this the proper way to use reflection?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your code isn't working, and the non-Honeycomb notification is being used. Try this to detect Honeycomb or later:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Notification.BigPictureStyle? It should do the job.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigPictureStyle.html